# replace multiple rows with another string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a sample dataframe

```
id     food_item
1      Apple
2      Beet root
3      Pizza
5      Red velvet
```

I need to replace `apple` with `fruit`, `Beetroot` with `vegetable`, `pizza` with 'fast food'.

```
df['food_item'] = df['food_item'].str.replace('apple','fruit')
df['food_item'] = df['food_item'].str.replace('beetroot','vegetable')
df['food_item'] = df['food_item'].str.replace('pizza','fast food')
df['food_item'] = df['food_item'].str.replace('red velvet','dessert')
```

But is there any more simplified/alternative way instead of writing four lines for this using regex, so that `blue velvet` can also be replace with `dessert` though it is not currently added in df.

---

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! You should look into [pandas replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and not python's built-in:

```
df['food_item'] = df['food_item'].replace({'apple':'fruit','beetroot':'vegetable','pizza':'fast food','red velvet':'dessert'})
```

Also if multiple strings should be replaced into a common string you can try:

```
df['food_item'] = df['food_item'].replace(['apple','banana','orange','grapes'],'fruit')
```

Given you edit you can create a dictionary of replacements to pass it to pandas' replace. One useful thing about the function is that if the value is not found it will just simply skip it and no generate an error. Therefore, you can add blue velvet to your dictionary or replacements without any consequences so that when blue velvet is part of the data it gets replaced, otherwise it's skipped

Comment: Celius, I've just edited my question.

Comment: Thanks aristotle, but what's the regular expression you are looking for? A fruit is not fruit because of regular expression but because of a language definition

Comment: Its more like `contains`. If the row contains the matching string, it should replace with another.